# Hausdorff dimension of a subset of Cantor set

Tags: hausdorff-dimension, fractals

What is the Hausdorff dimension of the subset
$$F := \{ x = \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{2 x_n}{3^n} \in [0,1] : x_n \in \{ 0 , 1 \} , x_n = 1 \Rightarrow x_{n+1}=0 \}$$
of the Cantor set? Is it known already?

As far as I know, this set can be corresponded to a binary tree related to the Fibonacci sequence. (I don't know how to call that tree.)

Comment: Presumably, the subscript $n$ on the last $x$ should be $n+1$.  Then, at stage $n$ of the usual middle-thirds construction of the Cantor set, when you have $2^n$ intervals of length $1/3^n$ each, the number of those intervals that meet $F$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number (if you index the Fibonacci numbers appropriately), which is asymptotically a constant time $\phi^n$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt 5)/2$.  So I'd expect the Hausdorff dimension of $F$ to be $(\ln\phi)/(\ln 3)$.

Comment: If so, then you can brake your set in two parts, those which start with $1,0$ and the rest. These parts are rescalings of the original set with coefficients 
$\tfrac19$ and $\tfrac13$ therefore dimension is the number $\alpha$ such that
$$\tfrac 1{3^\alpha}+\tfrac1{9^\alpha}=1.$$

Comment: Edit: $x_n=1 \Rightarrow x_{n+1}=0$.

Comment: See related math.SE question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73547/uncountable-sets-of-hausdorff-dimension-zero

Comment: Thanks for your replies~
@Anton, I'm still uncertain about one point. At step n+1, the part starting with 1 doesn't seem to be exactly a self-similar part of the set at step n. And why is the ratio $\frac{1}{9}$ for this part?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify my follow up question: is $F$ in question a self-similar set? If so, what are the self-similar mappings?

Comment: Yes, $F$ is self-similar, exactly as Anton described.  Writing $F_{10} = \{x\in F \mid x_0=1, x_1=0\}$ and $F_0 = \{x\in F \mid x_0 = 0\}$, we have $F = F_{10} \cup F_0$.  Furthermore, $F_0$ is a rescaling of $F$ with coefficient $\frac 13$, and $F_{10}$ is a rescaling of $F$ with coefficient $\frac 19$.  (This is just a fleshed-out version of Anton's comment.)

Comment: The self-similar mappings are $F_{10} \to F$, $x\mapsto 9x - 6$, and $F_0 \to F$, $x\mapsto 3x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments by Andreas and Anton give you the answer already to your specific question.  Let me give a more general answer, since your question is very representative of a whole class of examples.

The condition that $x_n = 1 \Rightarrow x_{n+1} = 0$ is a *Markov* condition: the value of $x_{n+1}$ is restricted by the value of $x_n$.  In your case you are considering all sequences in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ such that the symbol $1$ cannot follow itself; one could also consider more symbols and more complicated restrictions, such as "every occurrence of $2$ can only be followed by $0$ or $2$, but not $1$".  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subshift_of_finite_type for more details.

Subshifts of finite type (abbreviated SFTs) are also called topological Markov chains, and can be presented in terms of a transition matrix, as described in that Wikipedia article.  The logarithm of the largest eigenvalue of the transition matrix is an important quantity called the *[topological entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_entropy)* of the SFT.

When you construct a subset of the Cantor set as in your question, the topological entropy turns out to be directly related to the Hausdorff dimension: namely Hausdorff dimension is topological entropy divided by $\log \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the contraction ratio at each step of the construction of the Cantor set.

We wrote a more detailed description of this in Pesin & Climenhaga, "Lectures on fractal geometry and dynamical systems", or you can find many parts of it in most standard textbooks on dynamical systems.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying whether the set $F$ is self-similar or not?